# What methods are used for differentiating between production/staging/development environments in PHP applications?

Tags: php, configuration, release, development-environment, production-environment

Obviously this is a common issue: we have PHP web applications that are managed by git or other SCMs, and are deployed (ideally) in 3+ different environments that should be extremely similar. The only differences should be in the specific configuration such as addressing of external resources (eg: database host, memcache, etc).

Here are the three methods I've seen or used:

1. Maintain an array of hostnames => environment types:
   `$hosts = array ('host1.example.com' => 'production', 'staging.example.com' => 'staging' ...)`
2. Have a config file that is in the .gitignore (or equivalent for other SCMs) with an example version to copy and edit
3. Use `http.conf` to set an env_var: "SetEnv ENVIRONMENT dev" in your http.conf and then `$environment = get_env('ENVIRONMENT');` in your scripts.

Are there other methods as well? I know each of these have benefits and pitfalls--what are those?

Comment: I thought shops that use PHP didn't have prod/stage/dev differentiation :p

Comment: Very funny =) Just because PHP is the duct-tape of the internet doesn't mean that there aren't real coders who use it with rigor. I'm sure someone does... somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Jenkins to pull from git server whenever a push event is issued.

In it's config we have a line that is different for each server:

```
mv config_<env>.php config.php
```

while config.php is in git ignore.

Comment: So how does that line get executed? Does each server have the post_push hook installed when it is initially deployed?

Comment: the git server pings jenkins on push and then he executes a series of predefined commands starting with git pull then config thingy, executes unit/functional tests and then accepts the build or on failure reverts to previous good version and sends notices. checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software) or search for continuous integration. Will help alot.

Comment: We're getting set up to use Jenkins right now (we have it running); are you saying that you also use it to manage deployment to your production and staging machines directly?

Comment: what do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: I mean that in the sense that Jenkins actually runs commands on the target hosts to deploy the new versions after successful builds. How do you accomplish this? Do you do a `git push {production-servers}` from the Jenkins host?

Answer (score 4):

On *nix:

- You can set environment variables directly in `/etc/environment` to apply them system-wide.
- You can set environment variables for Apache only in `/etc/apache2/envvars` (Ubuntu) or `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` (CentOS).

Since environment configuration is environment-specific and not application-specific, it doesn't make sense to use a `.htaccess` or other application config file to set these.

Comment: Much cleaner option in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use set environment option can be done by any major server.
Default to production if it is not defined.

This way you will not have to maintain list of servers. And can keep it out of git

Comment: What about cli then? should you just pass it in?

Comment: Does not meter for cli, as user will never be able to see output anyway. So just work with cli same way does not meter the server.

Answer (score 0):

The web application I've been working on for the past couple of years uses a Java API backend with a PHP layer on the front for templating etc. We use Maven to control the difference in environments.

I'm not entirely sure how it all fits together as I didn't set it up myself. What we have though is a large settings.xml document separated into various environments. Configuration options are then pulled from this file depending on the environment.

Similar to [Udan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750153/udan) we also use Jenkins to pull it all together when publishing to dev/staging/live.

It appears there is a Maven specifically designed for PHP here: http://www.php-maven.org/
I've never used it so can't say how useful it would be, worth a look though maybe.